# How can I invest in Asian and African Markets?

Tags: united-kingdom, markets, world

With a great deal of growth happening in Asian and African markets, I would like to know what are the options for investing in these areas.  I'm UK based.

Comment: Where are you located? The options may differ if you live in various other countries as US citizens may have different choices from someone living in France I'd imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of restricting yourself on a geographical basis, I would consider two markets that seem to fit the bill based on your question:

- [Emerging markets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerging_markets): the four major countries in this category are the BRICS group- Brazil, Russia, India, China and South Africa. Growth is aggressive when the going is good but volatility tends to be high as well.
- [Frontier markets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_markets): includes countries like Argentina and Bangladesh where the potential is high but the market is not as liquid and investment opportunities are not as easy to find (relative to emerging markets).

Once you've decided on your risk appetite, I would consider using an ETF to buy in to these markets:

- [Top emerging market ETF's](http://etfdb.com/etfdb-category/emerging-markets-equities/)
- [Top frontier and "next-emerging" market ETF's](http://etfdb.com/type/region/frontier-markets/)